# My attachment serve has error with Couldn't find Attachment with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have my attachment model related to test_suite model. I'm able to upload a file to my database. I was able to seen the content of my uploaded files. I implemented a serve method and the URL I got when I want to see the file is correct. However, I'm getting "Couldn't find Attachment with 'id'= "

controllers/attachment_controller.rb:

```
def serve
        @attachment = Attachment.find(params[:id]) # this is the line generating the error
        send_data(@attachment.file_contents, :filename => "#{@attachment.attach_file_name}",
                                            :type => @attachment.attach_content_type,
                                            :size => @attachment.attach_file_size,
                                            :disposition => "inline")
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :test_suites do
    resources :attachments, :only => [:create, :new, :destroy,:show] do
      get "serve"  # since serve is not a restfull route, it need to be under it's resource
    end
  end
```

model/attachment.rb:

```
class Attachement < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :test_suite
    has_attached_file :attach

    validates_attachment_content_type :attach, :content_type => ["text/xml", "text/plain","text/html"], :message => 'File must be txt, xml, or html'

    # create a function that sets the uploadedFile object attributes to our newly created file.
    def attach=(attach)
        # read allows us to process the data and read from it
        self.file_contents = attach.read
        self.attach_file_name = attach.original_filename
        self.attach_content_type = attach.content_type
        self.attach_file_size = attach.size
    end
end
```

views/test_suites/show.html.erb:

```
<% test_suite.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
    <p><%= link_to attachment.attach_file_name.split('.').first, test_suite_attachement_serve_path(test_suite,attachment)%> </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: The route for `get "serve"` is missing the `to: "attachments#serve"` argument. Assuming the controller is named AttachmentsController. Also your attachment model is misspelled Attach*e*ment it should be Attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in member block

```
resources :test_suites do 
  resources :attachments, :only => [:create, :new, :destroy,:show] do 
    member do
      get :serve # since serve is not a restfull route, it need to be under it's resource
    end
  end 
end
```

This will generate following route for you

```
/test_suites/attachments/:id/serve
```

Comment: This is not working for me. After I added the member, I changed the link path to serve_test_suite_attachement_path(test_suite,attachment) and I got this error now "uninitialized constant AttachementsController"

Comment: I found that my attachment_controller file was gone. It seems to happen some times when I have Atom open and switch between branches. I got it back now and the serve is working. Thanks alot Deepak.